# Manually Converting rgba8 to rgba5551

Tags: opengl-es, rgba

I need to convert rgba8 to rgba5551 manually. I found some helpful code from another post and want to modify it to convert from rgba8 to rgba5551. I don't really have experience with bitewise stuff and haven't had any luck messing with the code myself.

```
void* rgba8888_to_rgba4444( void* src, int src_bytes)
{
    // compute the actual number of pixel elements in the buffer.
    int num_pixels = src_bytes / 4;
    unsigned long*  psrc = (unsigned long*)src;
    unsigned short* pdst = (unsigned short*)src;
    // convert every pixel
    for(int i = 0; i < num_pixels; i++){
        // read a source pixel
        unsigned px = psrc[i];
        // unpack the source data as 8 bit values
        unsigned r = (px << 8)  & 0xf000;
        unsigned g = (px >> 4)  & 0x0f00;
        unsigned b = (px >> 16) & 0x00f0;
        unsigned a = (px >> 28) & 0x000f;
        // and store
        pdst[i] = r | g | b | a;
    }
    return pdst;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of RGBA5551 is that it has color info condensed into 16 bits - or two bytes, with only one bit for the alpha channel (on or off). RGBA8888, on the other hand, uses a byte for each channel. (If you don't need an alpha channel, I hear RGB565 is better - as humans are more sensitive to green). Now, with 5 bits, you get the numbers 0 through 31, so r, g, and b each need to be converted to some number between 0 and 31, and since they are originally a byte each (0-255), we multiply each by 31/255. Here is a function that takes RGBA bytes as input and outputs RGBA5551 as a short:

```
short int RGBA8888_to_RGBA5551(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b, unsigned char a){
    unsigned char r5 = r*31/255; // All arithmetic is integer arithmetic, and so floating points are truncated. If you want to round to the nearest integer, adjust this code accordingly.
    unsigned char g5 = g*31/255;
    unsigned char b5 = b*31/255;
    unsigned char a1 = (a > 0) ? 1 : 0; // 1 if a is positive, 0 else. You must decide what is sensible.

    // Now that we have our 5 bit r, g, and b and our 1 bit a, we need to shift them into place before combining.

    short int rShift = (short int)r5 << 11; // (short int)r5 looks like 00000000000vwxyz - 11 zeroes. I'm not sure if you need (short int), but I've wasted time tracking down bugs where I didn't typecast properly before shifting.
    short int gShift = (short int)g5 << 6;
    short int bShift = (short int)b5 << 1;

    // Combine and return
    return rShift | gShift | bShift | a1;
}
```

You can, of course condense this code.